# laravel 5.4: Undefined property: Illuminate\Validation\Validator::$errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, email-verification

I have here a code in email validation wherein users register and upon registering he would accept a registration confirmation email. I'm using laravel make auth with modification to include sending tokens to valid email. Upon successful registering a confirmation message should appear but it wouldn't.

here's the code:

RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\HTTP\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    protected function register(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = $this->validator($input);

        if ($validator->passes()){
            $data = $this->create($input)->toArray();
            $data['token'] = str_random(25);

            $user= User::find($data['id']);
            $user->token=$data['token'];
            $user->save();

            Mail::send('mail.confirmation', $data, function($message) use($data){
                $message->to($data['email']);
                $message->subject('Registration Confirmation');

            });
            return redirect(route('login'))->with('status','confirmation email has been sent');
        }
        return redirect(route('login'))->with('status', $validator->errors);
    }
    public function confirmation($token)
    {
        $user = User::where('token', $token)->first();
        if(!is_null($user)){
            $user->confirmed=1;
            $user->token='';
            $user->save();
            return redirect(route('login'))->with('status','complete actibeyt');
        }
        return redirect(route('login'))->with('status','something is wrong');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a property on the `Validator` called `errors`, however, there is a method.

Simple change:

```
return redirect(route('login'))->with('status', $validator->errors());
```

Answer (score 0):

First one replace your return function with this:-

```
return redirect()->route('login')->with('status','confirmation email has been sent');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already solved the immediate problem, but I created a web service to solve this particular pain point with no server-side code at all:  [clicktoverify.net](https://clicktoverify.net/). It just takes a single JS include and a few lines of code:

```
<form method="POST" action="whatever" id="my-form">
  <input type="email" name="email" />
  <input type="submit" name="sign up!" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.clicktoverify.net/ctv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
form = document.getElementById("my-form");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  alert("We've sent a verification email to this address. Please check your inbox.");
  verifier = new CTV();
  verifier.verify({
      email: form['email'].value,
      public_api_key: "71917c69-b8e8-3992-adf5-c2de3b89c17e", //you'll get your own when you create an account
      success: function(xhr) {
          alert("Your email address is verified!");
          form.submit();
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
          alert("Something went wrong! We couldn't verify your email address.");
      }
    });
});
</script>
```